# Easypiechart angularJs change color

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to use ha angularJs version of easypiechart to create a simple scale color on value change. The color should change when value change, from red to green.

In the old easypiechart version, jquery based, this was possible by doing something similar:

```
barColor: function(percent) {
    percent /= 100;
    return "rgb(" + Math.round(255 * (1-percent)) + ", " + Math.round(255 * percent) + ", 0)";
}
```

I've made a plunker to demonstarete what I'm trying to do, upside is angular, downside is jquery: http://plnkr.co/edit/7yQ1SiIPHFh62yxwnW9e?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you, except that I was using the easy pie chart in a more complex directive I defined myself. I was having a heck of a time figuring out how I could pass the percentage and options model variables on the scope and making changes when the attributes of the outer directive changed. Because of this, I abandoned the angular version of easyPieChart and went back to the jQuery version (which was probably me and not the easypiechart directive, as I am new to angular so I struggle with some of the concepts).

Here is a simplified version of my code showing what I did:

My Directive infoBox.js:

```
'use strict';

commonApp.directive('infoBox', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      percent: '@',
      text: '@',
      content: '@',
      textIsNumber: '@'
    },
    templateUrl: '/directives/infoBox.html',
    controller: 'infoBoxController',
    }
  };
});
```

My Template infoBox.html

```
<div class="infobox">
  <div class="infobox-progress">
    <div class="easy-pie-chart percentage" data-percent="{{percent}}" data-size="50">
      <span class="percent">{{percent}}</span>%
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="infobox-data">
    <span ng-class="{'infobox-data-number': textIsNumber, 'infobox-text': !textIsNumber}" class="infobox-data-number">{{text}}</span>

    <div class="infobox-content">
      {{content}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my Controller infoBoxController.js

```
'use strict';

commonApp.controller('infoBoxController',
  function infoboxController($scope, $log, $attrs, $element) {
    var init = function () {
      var $chart = $element.find('.easy-pie-chart.percentage')[0];
      var barColor = $element.data('color') || (!$element.hasClass('infobox-dark') ? $element.css('color') : 'rgba(255,255,255,0.95)');
      var trackColor = barColor == 'rgba(255,255,255,0.95)' ? 'rgba(255,255,255,0.25)' : '#E2E2E2';
      $($chart).easyPieChart({
        barColor: barColorFunction,
        trackColor: trackColor,
        scaleColor: false,
        lineCap: 'butt',
        lineWidth: parseInt(size / 10),
        animate: /msie\s*(8|7|6)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()) ? false : 1000,
        size: size
      });
    };
    var barColorFunction = function (percent) {
      if (percent <= 100) {
        return ($element.data('color') || (!$element.hasClass('infobox-dark') ? $element.css('color') : 'rgba(255,255,255,0.95)'));
      } else {
        return ('rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7)');
      }
    };

    init();
    var update = function () {
      var $chart = $element.find('.easy-pie-chart.percentage')[0];
      $($chart).data('easyPieChart').update($attrs.percent);
    };
    $scope.$watch(function () {
      return [$attrs.percent];
    }, update, true);
  }
);
```

Directive Usage:

```
    <info-box class="infobox-blue2" percent="{{modelPercent}}" text="describes pie chart" text-is-number="false" content="more describing pie chart"></info-box>
```

I have a watch on my attribute percent, which runs the straight jquery update function. And the barColorFunction is what controls what color I display.

Circumstances are slightly different, but I hope this helps.